# finding all keywords and its index in a text with exact match c#

Tags: c#, regex, algorithm, full-text-search

I have a List of keywords and a text to search them for. I need to get the start index of each found keywords within the text and the match must be exact. For example:

```
keywords=>cat,dog
text=> a catchy cat with a dogged dog
```

Here while matching only 'cat' and 'dog' match with index must be returned and match should not be with words like 'catchy' and 'dogged'

I have tried [Aho-Corasick Algorithm for string matching](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12383/Aho-Corasick-string-matching-in-C) but it matches 'catchy' and 'dogged' also. How do I do exact match of the keywords and return the index position within the text using c#

Comment: This is one time search, or multiple? If multiple text or keywords a constantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex with boundary..

```
var results= keywords.Select(x=>
                               new
                               {
                                word=x,
                                indexes=Regex.Matches(input,@"\b"+x+@"\b")
                                             .Cast<Match>().Select(y=>y.Index)
                                             .ToList()    
                               }
                            );
```

---

You can now iterate over result

```
foreach(var match in results)
{
    match.word;
    foreach(int index in match.indexes)//index
}
```

Comment: is the Linq method efficient for large text and say 10K keywords?

Comment: @jeff ahh..yes performance would be an issue but it's not specific to LINQ..matching 10k keywords over a 100mb text file would certainly take time!I would use thread's or Task to run it asynchronously without blocking..

Comment: I will give it a try and come up with feedback. BTW

Answer (score 1):

You can do a little modification with Aho-Corasick Algorithm.
For all the keywords, append word separator(such as space, dot, newline etc.)to the end of each keyword.

So if you have m keywords and the text has n types of separators, you will build the trie tree from n*m words.

After appending the separator, it will not match 'catchy' and 'dogged' in your sample case.

Edit:

First you'd better have a understanding of AC algorithm.

Example:

keywords=>cat,dog and text=> a catchy cat with a dogged dog

Now changed keywords=>'cat ','dog ', 'cat\n', 'dog\n' (just append space and newline separators)

changed text=>'a catchy cat with a dogged dog\n'

Then you can use the standord  Aho-Corasick Algorithm for string finding each index of every keyword.

Suppose the length of text is n, and the total length keywords is m, the Aho-Corasick Algorithm has an O(n+m) complexity which is sufficient for large text and large keyword set.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below function will return you the list of indexes for each keyword.

```
private List<int> GetIndexForKeyWord(string content,string key)
{
    int index = 0;
    List<int> indexes=new List<int>();
    while (index < content.Length && index >= 0)
    {
        index = content.IndexOf(key, index);
        if (index+key.Length==content.Length||index >= 0 && !char.IsLetter(content[index + key.Length]))
        {
            indexes.Add(index);
        }
        if(index!=-1)
            index++;
    }
    return indexes;
}
```

Comment: IndexOutOfRange for last keyword in text.

Comment: @Толя: Thanks for pointing that out. Changed the code.

Answer (score 0):

Split text by words and push all words into `Dictionary<word, index>` and lookup into dictionary for each keyword.